# Extract all the sentences that contain preposition "to" in Penn Treebank

Tags: python, nltk

I'm doing a homework using python. The idea is that i need to extract all the sentences containing the verb "give" and the preposition "to" (e.g. I give the bouquet *to* the girl). I have come up with a code that reports to me errors of incorrect space of indentation. I don't know what goes wrong. Here's the code I wrote:

```
import nltk

from nltk import treebank

for filename in nltk.corpus.treebank.fileids():

    files=open(filename,'r')

    file=files.read()

    for sentence in file:

        a=sentence.index('to')
        #a=the position in which 'to' appears

        b=sentence.index('give')
        #b=the position in which 'give' appears

        mylist=[]

        if a!=-1 and b!=-1:
                #if a and b exist simultaneously
                mylist.append(sentence)

                print(mylist)
                new_file_name='List'+'.txt'
                #create a new file

                file=open(new_file_name,'w')
                for sentence in file:
                    file.write(sentence)
                    file.write('\n')
                file.close()
```

Could someone help me out?

Comment: oops, the copy and paste runs into some problem. Suppose the b=sentence.index('give') is correctly indented and so forth.

Comment: Use the `RegexParser`: http://www.nltk.org/howto/chunk.html . Since this a a homework question, most probably you won't get an answer on SO.